# Getting the dark mode of github in Spyder IDE

Tags: spyder

Recently, Github announced the dark mode. The CSS it is using for displaying code is much more appealing to the eyes. I want the color code of Github dark mode so that I could personalize my IDE in Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Unfortunately that's not possible, sorry.